# Parsing data with inconsistencies and checking for null / non-existant items

Tags: javascript, null

I am looping through data that in a perfect world would look like:

- item.dataone
- item.datatwo
- item.datathree
- item.datafour

However, sometimes one or more of these items does not even exist, so the file could look like (or worse):

- item.dataone
- item.datathree
- item.datafour

I have declared vars:

```
var one;
var two;
var three;
var four;
```

I am checking the item using a simple exist function like so:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
     one = exists(item.dataone);
     two = exists(item.dataone);
     three = exists(item.dataone);
     four = exists(item.dataone);
}

function exists(item){
if(item){
    console.log(item);
    return item;
}
else{
    console.log("none");
    return "none";
}
}
```

If an item exists, but is empty, none shows, however, when I get to an item that does not exist (item.datatwo from example list above), i get the error:

```
cannot read description of NULL
```

I guess I am not clear on why my check isn't working? If it doesn't exist throw false right and give the var the "none"?

What do I do if an item does not exist in my loop?

Confused noob.

EDIT: here is some real data example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "SITE/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Green%20Teams')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {



                title = item.Title;
                regionname = item.Region_x0020_Name;
                forestorunit = item.Forest_x0020_or_x0020_Unit;
                districtorunit = item.District_x0020_or_x0020_Unit;
                orglocation = item.Org_x0020_Location;
                members = item.Members;
                greenteamdescription = item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website.Description;
                greenteamurl = item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website.Url; 
                locationcity = item.Location_x0020_City;
                locationstate = item.Location_x0020_State;
                locationzip = item.Location_x0020_Zip;

            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });

<d:Title>NNFG Green Team</d:Title>
                <d:Region_x0020_Name>02 - Rocky Mountain Region</d:Region_x0020_Name>
                <d:Forest_x0020_or_x0020_Unit>07 - Nebraska NF</d:Forest_x0020_or_x0020_Unit>
                <d:District_x0020_or_x0020_Sub_x002 m:null="true" />
                <d:Org_x0020_Location>Forest</d:Org_x0020_Location>
                <d:Members m:null="true" />
                <d:Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website m:null="true" />
                <d:Location_x0020_City>Chadron</d:Location_x0020_City>
                <d:Location_x0020_State>NE</d:Location_x0020_State>
                <d:Location_x0020_Zip>69337</d:Location_x0020_Zip>
                <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">42.829419</d:Latitude>
                <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">-102.999907</d:Longitude>

<d:Title>GMFL NF Sustainability Team</d:Title>
                <d:Region_x0020_Name>09 - Eastern Region</d:Region_x0020_Name>
                <d:Forest_x0020_or_x0020_Unit>20 - Green Mtn and Finger Lakes NFs</d:Forest_x0020_or_x0020_Unit>
                <d:District_x0020_or_x0020_Sub_x002 m:null="true" />
                <d:Org_x0020_Location>Forest</d:Org_x0020_Location>
                <d:Members>John and Sal</d:Members>
                <d:Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue">
                    <d:Description>GMFL NF Sustainability Team Intranet Site</d:Description>
                    <d:Url>http://fsweb.gm.r9.fs.fed.us/library2/sustainability/index.htm</d:Url>
                </d:Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website>
                <d:Location_x0020_City>Rutland</d:Location_x0020_City>
                <d:Location_x0020_State>Vermont</d:Location_x0020_State>
                <d:Location_x0020_Zip>05701</d:Location_x0020_Zip>
                <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">43.615355</d:Latitude>
                <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">-72.922433</d:Longitude>
```

The issue is Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website either has Description and URL or not... Exists or doesn't...

Comment: your check is a function that has a parameter. But if item doesnt exist how can you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: right right... ya that makes complete sense. So if it doesn't exist, then what? How do I assign my variable something else?

Comment: @Craicerjack You can pass undefined as a parameter

Comment: @SimpleJ ahh so the error is thrown later on when he tries to do something with the var that has a null value?

Comment: The above error would be thrown by trying to access the key "description" in a variable who's value is null. Like this: `bar.description` or `bar['description']` (where bar is null).

Comment: @SimpleJ cool cheers. Learn something new everyday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can default a variable by using the `||` operator like this:

```
var foo = bar || "this is the default value if bar is falsey";
```

The issue in your code is this line:

`greenteamdescription = item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website.Description;`

If `item` or `Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website` are falsey, you will receive an error. There are multiple methods for avoiding this issue. The simplest is to default the objects to blank objects like this:

`greenteamdescription = ((item || {}).Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website || {}).Description;`

This insures that even if `item` or `Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website` is falsey, no error will be thrown. However `greenteamdescription` will be undefined if either `item` or `Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website` are falsey.

You could run into the same issue on this line:

`greenteamurl = item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website.Url;`

There are more robust systems for handling this kind of issue. Such as "brototype":
https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype

Comment: I still get NULL because item.datatwo isn't even an object that get's touched by my loop since it doesn't exist.

Comment: @jasonflaherty is `item` null or is `item.datatwo` null?

Comment: item contains other data. item.dataone, item.datathree, item.datafour for example is still there. item.datatwo is not in the output. This is where I thought the use of variables would help, since i could do just as you defined in your answer...

Comment: You can default object members using the same technique. Like this:
`item.datatwo = item.datatwo || "default datatwo value";`

Comment: I added some real data into the question... maybe that will help? item.datatwo = item.datatwo || "defaut" still returned null.... and also made the items with data undefined.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code accessing this data as well.

Comment: I think since I am checking item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website.Description, if item.Green_x0020_Team_x0020_Website comes back null, then so would the .description

Comment: use the || when youre setting the data. ` title = item.Title || "the title you want it to have";   regionname = item.Region_x0020_Name || "your default data";`  etc etc
               `

Comment: I've updated my answer now that you've posted your code.

Comment: Excellent update! This is really good: foo = bar || "Default";

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
     item = item || {};
     one = exists(item.dataone);
     two = exists(item.dataone);
     three = exists(item.dataone);
     four = exists(item.dataone);
}
```

If item is null it will be defaulted to object and there will be no error.

Comment: item exists - just item.datatwo doesnt